# Internationalization (translation) of dialog and the main window in a pyqt5 application

Tags: python, internationalization, pyqt5, translation, pyside2

I am trying to translate my small application written in pyside2/pyqt5 to several languages, for example, Chinese. After googling, I managed to change the main window to Chinese after select from the menu -> language -> Chinese. However, the pop up dialog from menu -> option still remains English version. It seems the translation info is not transferred to the dialog. How do I solve this?

Basically, I build two ui files in designer and convert to two python files:One mainui.py and one dialogui.py. I then convert the two python file into one *.ts file using

```
pylupdate5 -verbose mainui.py dialogui.py -ts zh_CN.ts
```

after that, in linguist input the translation words. I can see the items in the dialog, which means this information is not missing. Then I release the file as zh_CN.qm file. All this supporting file I attached below using google drive.

[Supporting files for the question](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uFjuGQ-_SF1y6EqEUNIWHgDP5dkKHC0m)

The main file is as

```
import os
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainui import Ui_MainWindow

from dialogui import Ui_Dialog

class OptionsDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.retranslateUi(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionConfigure.triggered.connect(self.showdialog)
        self.actionChinese.triggered.connect(self.change_lang)

    def showdialog(self):
        dlg = OptionsDialog(self)
        dlg.exec_()

    def change_lang(self):
        trans = QtCore.QTranslator()
        trans.load('zh_CN')
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().installTranslator(trans)
    self.retranslateUi(self)



if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

I think it should be a typical task because almost no application will only have a mainwindow.

Comment: Yes, @eyllanesc. Your solution works pretty well and  I just marked your answer as the accepted solution. I did not do so immediately just because I want to  really sit down to analyze  your code thoroughly and asked you about the parts I cannot understand well. Anyway, I can ask you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `changeEvent()` method and call `retranslateUi()` when the event is of type `QEvent::LanguageChange`, on the other hand the `QTranslator` object must be a member of the class but it will be deleted and it will not exist when the `changeEvent()` method is called.

Finally assuming that the Language menu is used to establish only translations, a possible option is to establish the name of the .qm as data of the `QAction`s and to use the triggered method of the `QMenu` as I show below:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainui import Ui_MainWindow

from dialogui import Ui_Dialog

class OptionsDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.LanguageChange:
            self.retranslateUi(self)
        super(OptionsDialog, self).changeEvent(event)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.m_translator = QtCore.QTranslator(self)
        self.actionConfigure.triggered.connect(self.showdialog)
        self.menuLanguage.triggered.connect(self.change_lang)
        # set translation for each submenu
        self.actionChinese.setData('zh_CN')

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def showdialog(self):
        dlg = OptionsDialog(self)
        dlg.exec_()

    @QtCore.Slot(QtWidgets.QAction)
    def change_lang(self, action):
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().removeTranslator(self.m_translator)
        if self.m_translator.load(action.data()):
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().installTranslator(self.m_translator)

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.LanguageChange:
            self.retranslateUi(self)
        super(MainWindow, self).changeEvent(event)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```